# Bootstrap Menu disappears on Phone

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, windows-phone-8

Using Bootstrap menu and on resizing screen everything works well, however when I access the site from a Windows Phone I have the menu icon on the right is not there?? Menu Code:

```
div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Madcaps Out Of School Club</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">PAGES <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Activities", "Activities", "Home")</li>
                        @Html.Action("ListPages", "Home")
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Ran through HTML validator and everything and can't fault anything.  Tested on other devices (iPad, Nexus, etc) and shows up ok just not on phone. Unfortunately don't have another phone to test with here to see if it's just Windows Phones, however I have tested with iPhone Emulators that are ok.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following code from your Responsive CSS.

```
@-ms-viewport {
  width: device-width;
}
```